# How to add an auto-incrementing primary key to an existing table, in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a table with existing data. Is there a way to add a primary key without deleting and re-creating the table?

Answer (score 540, accepted):

(*Updated - Thanks to the people who commented*)

## Modern Versions of PostgreSQL

Suppose you have a table named `test1`, to which you want to add an auto-incrementing, primary-key `id` (surrogate) column. The following command should be sufficient in recent versions of PostgreSQL:

```
   ALTER TABLE test1 ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

## Older Versions of PostgreSQL

In old versions of PostgreSQL (prior to 8.x?) you had to do all the dirty work. The following sequence of commands should do the trick:

```
  ALTER TABLE test1 ADD COLUMN id INTEGER;
  CREATE SEQUENCE test_id_seq OWNED BY test1.id;
  ALTER TABLE test1 ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq');
  UPDATE test1 SET id = nextval('test_id_seq');
```

Again, in recent versions of Postgres this is roughly equivalent to the single command above.

Comment: I am using ORACLE, so sharing it might be useful for ORACLE guys   In ORACLE :     ALTER TABLE TEST1 ADD ID NUMBER;                 UPDATE TEST1 SET ID =  TEST1_SEQ.NEXTVAL;   ALTER TABLE TEST1 ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);      create a Sequence TEST1_SEQ before executing UPDATE statement

Comment: Note that `ADD PRIMARY KEY` also creates a `NOT NULL` constraint (tested in postgres 9.3) as expected and wanted.

Comment: Further to @resnyanskiy's comment, this will work even when there's data in the table. IDs are populated and not null constraint is set. The entire answer can be replaced by the line in that comment.

Comment: You don't need the 2nd line at all, actually it's bad to add the 2nd line, because after the first line, the id column is added, and all existing rows already have an auto increased id, you u execute the 2nd line again, then all id will be changed re-base start from N+1, where N is count of existing rows.

Comment: @EricWang Thanks, Eric, you're right - I believe that this didn't work some versions (years) ago, but I'm not sure. Turned the answer into community-wiki.

Comment: is it possible to make primary key(serial) without adding new column

Comment: alter column datatype !

Comment: The doc history for Postgres suggests the SERIAL datatype was added in 7.2: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/datatype.html vs. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/datatype.html. 7.2 was released in 2002, so it seems safe to assume most modern Postgres installations will support it.

Comment: It seems that for compatibility and less problem with permission, is better to use the "IDENTITY" type from Postgress 10+
Check https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/

Comment: Do we know how postgres generate SEQUENCE to existing table? Example order by created_at or id?

Comment: What about large tables? Do these statements lock for a long time?

Comment: When using the `ALTER TABLE <table> ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`, how can you specify the `id` to be `bigint`?

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos Just replace SERIAL -> BIGSERIAL

Comment: Using this, is it possible to specify the order in which the new primary key ids are assigned?  For example, based on the sort order of a specific column?

Comment: @SirachMatthews See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370072/add-auto-increment-column-to-existing-table-ordered-by-date

Comment: How can I do the same thing but with an existing primary key column? If a primary key constraint was added but forgot to make it auto-increment

Comment: Found an answer. `ALTER TABLE ALTER column ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;`. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/285869/add-auto-increment-to-already-existing-primary-key-column-postgresql

Answer (score 79):

```
ALTER TABLE test1 ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

This is all you need to:

1. Add the `id` column
2. Populate it with a sequence from 1 to count(*).
3. Set it as primary key / not null.

Credit is given to @resnyanskiy who gave this answer in a comment.

Comment: This should be marked as answer, and the answer should belong to @resnyanskiy

Comment: I had to first drop the pkey and then run this.

`ALTER TABLE <table> DROP CONSTRAINT <pkey_name>;`

Answer (score 20):

To use an identity column in v10,

```
ALTER TABLE test 
ADD COLUMN id { int | bigint | smallint}
GENERATED { BY DEFAULT | ALWAYS } AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY;
```

For an explanation of identity columns, see https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/.

For the difference between GENERATED BY DEFAULT and GENERATED ALWAYS, see https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/sequences-gains-and-pitfalls/.

For altering the sequence, see https://popsql.io/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-alter-sequence-in-postgresql/.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if the table already contains rows then you get an error: `SQL Error [23502]: ERROR: column "id" contains null values`

Comment: @isapir: There was a bug in early versions (pg 10 and 10.1) producing this error. It was fixed with pg 10.2. Details here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/200143/3684

Answer (score 7):

I landed here because I was looking for something like that too. In my case, I was copying the data from a set of staging tables with many columns into one table while also assigning row ids to the target table. Here is a variant of the above approaches that I used. 
I added the serial column at the end of my target table. That way I don't have to have a placeholder for it in the Insert statement. Then a simple select * into the target table auto populated this column. Here are the two SQL statements that I used on PostgreSQL 9.6.4.

```
ALTER TABLE target ADD COLUMN some_column SERIAL;
INSERT INTO target SELECT * from source;
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand it's been a lot of years, but this may help other users.
Try to use first query:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo."Users"
ALTER COLUMN "UserID" 
ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1)
```

second query for update current value:

```
SELECT setval('"Users_UserID_seq"', (SELECT max("UserID")+1 FROM dbo."Users"), false)
```

where "Users" - table, "UserID" - primary key

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE test1 ADD id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30105672)

Comment: @yaseer thanks for your answer it works great

Answer (score 1):

I have Postgres 15.4

For example

- table: 'post'.
- column: 'id' primary column integer, without auto increment.

---

1 - Add `GENERATED IDENTITY`

```
ALTER TABLE post ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
```

2 - Set sequence value of `MAX(id)` or `1` if there is no record

```
SELECT SETVAL(pg_get_serial_sequence(post, 'id'), COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id) FROM post) + 1, 1))
```

Read about:

1. Parameter `GENERATED` `BY DEFAULT` and `ALWAYS`
2. Sequence in Postgres