# Adding 'serial' to existing column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a small table (~30 rows) in my Postgres 9.0 database with an integer ID field (the primary key) which currently contains unique sequential integers starting at 1, but which was not created using the 'serial' keyword.

How can I alter this table such that from now on inserts to this table will cause this field to behave as if it had been created with 'serial' as a type?

Comment: For modern Postgres version (>= 10) see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944499

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Look at the following commands (especially the commented block).

```
DROP TABLE foo;
DROP TABLE bar;

CREATE TABLE foo (a int, b text);
CREATE TABLE bar (a serial, b text);

INSERT INTO foo (a, b) SELECT i, 'foo ' || i::text FROM generate_series(1, 5) i;
INSERT INTO bar (b) SELECT 'bar ' || i::text FROM generate_series(1, 5) i;

-- blocks of commands to turn foo into bar
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_a_seq;
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN a SET DEFAULT nextval('foo_a_seq');
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN a SET NOT NULL;
ALTER SEQUENCE foo_a_seq OWNED BY foo.a;    -- 8.2 or later

SELECT MAX(a) FROM foo;
SELECT setval('foo_a_seq', 5);  -- replace 5 by SELECT MAX result

INSERT INTO foo (b) VALUES('teste');
INSERT INTO bar (b) VALUES('teste');

SELECT * FROM foo;
SELECT * FROM bar;
```

Comment: Since you're mentioning primary keys in your OP, you may also want to `ALTER TABLE foo ADD PRIMARY KEY (a)`.

Comment: SERIAL is syntactic sugar and is not stored in the DB metadata, so the code above would be 100% equivalent.

Comment: If there is a chance that the target table was created by a different user, you'd need to do `ALTER TABLE foo OWNER TO current_user;` first.

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `MAX(a)+1` in setval?
`SELECT MAX(a)+1 FROM foo; 
SELECT setval('foo_a_seq', 6);`

Answer (score 71):

You can also use `START WITH` to start a sequence from a particular point, although setval accomplishes the same thing, as in Euler's answer, eg,

```
SELECT MAX(a) + 1 FROM foo;
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_a_seq START WITH 12345; -- replace 12345 with max above
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN a SET DEFAULT nextval('foo_a_seq');
```

Answer (score 67):

## TL;DR

Here's a version where you don't need a human to read a value and type it out themselves.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_a_seq OWNED BY foo.a;
SELECT setval('foo_a_seq', coalesce(max(a), 0) + 1, false) FROM foo;
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN a SET DEFAULT nextval('foo_a_seq');
```

Another option would be to employ the reusable `Function` shared at the end of this answer.

---

## A non-interactive solution

Just adding to the other two answers, for those of us who need to have these `Sequence`s created by a **non-interactive script**, while patching a live-ish DB for instance.

That is, when you don't wanna `SELECT` the value manually and type it yourself into a subsequent `CREATE` statement.

In short, you can **not** do:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_a_seq
    START WITH ( SELECT max(a) + 1 FROM foo );
```

... since the `START [WITH]` clause in `CREATE SEQUENCE` expects a **value**, not a subquery.

> Note: As a rule of thumb, that applies to all non-CRUD (*i.e.*: anything other than `INSERT`, `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) statements in **pgSQL** AFAIK.

However, `setval()` does! Thus, the following is absolutely fine:

```
SELECT setval('foo_a_seq', max(a)) FROM foo;
```

If there's no data and you don't (want to) know about it, use `coalesce()` to set the default value:

```
SELECT setval('foo_a_seq', coalesce(max(a), 0)) FROM foo;
--                         ^      ^         ^
--                       defaults to:       0
```

However, having the current sequence value set to `0` is clumsy, if not illegal.
Using the three-parameter form of `setval` would be more appropriate:

```
--                                             vvv
SELECT setval('foo_a_seq', coalesce(max(a), 0) + 1, false) FROM foo;
--                                                  ^   ^
--                                                is_called
```

Setting the optional third parameter of `setval` to `false` will prevent the next `nextval` from advancing the sequence before returning a value, and thus:

> the next `nextval` will return exactly the specified value, and sequence advancement commences with the following `nextval`.

— from [this entry in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-sequence.html)

On an unrelated note, you also can specify the column owning the `Sequence` directly with `CREATE`, you don't have to alter it later:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_a_seq OWNED BY foo.a;
```

In summary:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_a_seq OWNED BY foo.a;
SELECT setval('foo_a_seq', coalesce(max(a), 0) + 1, false) FROM foo;
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN a SET DEFAULT nextval('foo_a_seq');
```

---

## Using a `Function`

Alternatively, if you're planning on doing this for multiple columns, you could opt for using an actual `Function`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_into_serial(table_name TEXT, column_name TEXT) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
    start_with INTEGER;
    sequence_name TEXT;
BEGIN
    sequence_name := table_name || '_' || column_name || '_seq';
    EXECUTE 'SELECT coalesce(max(' || column_name || '), 0) + 1 FROM ' || table_name
            INTO start_with;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE ' || sequence_name ||
            ' START WITH ' || start_with ||
            ' OWNED BY ' || table_name || '.' || column_name;
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' ALTER COLUMN ' || column_name ||
            ' SET DEFAULT nextVal(''' || sequence_name || ''')';
    RETURN start_with;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Use it like so:

```
INSERT INTO foo (data) VALUES ('asdf');
-- ERROR: null value in column "a" violates not-null constraint

SELECT make_into_serial('foo', 'a');
INSERT INTO foo (data) VALUES ('asdf');
-- OK: 1 row(s) affected
```

Comment: Great answer, but keep in mind `coalesce(max(a), 0))` won't work most of the time, since Ids usually start from 1. More correct  way would be `coalesce(max(a), 1))`

Comment: Thanks @Amiko for the comment! The `setval` function actually only sets the current "latest used value" for the sequence. The next **available** value (the first to be actually used) will be one more! Using `setval(..., coalesce(max(a), 1))` on an empty column would set it up to "start" with `2` (the next available value), as illustrated in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-sequence.html).

Comment: @Amiko You are right in saying there's a problem in my code, though: the `currval` should never be `0`, even if it wouldn't be reflected in the actual dataset. Using the three-parameter form of `setval` would be more appropriate: `setval(..., coalesce(max(a), 0) + 1, false)`. Answer updated accordingly!

Comment: Agreed, I totally missed that.
Thanks for the answer saved my time.

Answer (score 9):

### PostgreSQL 10 and later

[Don't use `serial`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial). Thanks to [the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490014/adding-serial-to-existing-column-in-postgres#comment100771118_9490014).

```sql
ALTER TABLE mysmalltable
ALTER COLUMN id
ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;
```

Answer (score 5):

### Working for me in `PostgreSQL 12`.

**It converts my existing int column to a serial column.**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('table_name_id_seq');
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN id SET NOT NULL;
ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq OWNED BY table_name.id;  
SELECT setval('table_name_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM table_name));
```

Comment: This results in a never-ending execution

Answer (score 0):

If you use a DBMS you can set the default value on the column as *Sequence*.

[image: default options]

It may be under advanced options.

[image: advanced default options]