# How to convert integer to serial

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which has a primary key column "gid" and its type is "Integer NOT NULL".
I want to convert it into "Serial NOT NULL" so that I can insert some values into this table.
I used following commands to convert it into serial:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_table_gid_seq
        INCREMENT 1
        MINVALUE 1
        MAXVALUE 2147483648 START 1
        CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN gid
        SET DEFAULT nextval('test_table_gid_seq'::regclass);
```

This command converted integer to serial. But while I entered some data to the table following error occurred:

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_test".

Please help me to solve this.  Is there any other method to convert integer to serial?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding 'serial' to existing column in Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490014/adding-serial-to-existing-column-in-postgres)

Answer (score 28):

Select max value of gid column (max_gid):

```
SELECT max(gid) FROM test_table;
```

And use it as start point for sequence (probably, max_gid+1):

```
ALTER SEQUENCE test_table_gid_seq RESTART WITH max_gid;
```

Comment: still not easy wrapper?