# How to change existing id columns to serial in one procedure? Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with a more than 100 tables. In each table i have column named id (int8 NOT NULL) with primary key. I would like to update whole database (all columns) to change this id type to SERIAL.

The reason is problem with inserting data. I would like to know how to write a procedure which will upadate in one shot all tables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490014/adding-serial-to-existing-column-in-postgres and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593946/postgresql-reconfigure-existing-table-changing-primary-key-to-type-serial

Comment: `SERIAL` isn't a type. You have to create a sequence, lock the table, alter the table default to use the sequence, update the sequence so the next value is the highest value in the table + 1, and commit. You can use a `DO` block that loops over `information_schema` to find columns and table names, and use PL/PgSQL `EXECUTE format(...)` dynamic queries to make the changes. See the numerous related posts for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename _fieldname_seq MAXVALUE 2147483647;

ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN code_f TYPE INTEGER;

ALTER TABLE public.fournisseur ALTER COLUMN code_f SET DEFAULT nextval('public.fournisseur_code_f_seq'::text);
```