# how to update the data type of a column without deleting the values in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I made a mistake by the creation of my table. The primary key was incorrect. I delete the constraint and now I don't have a primary key in my table, only the field with the data. Now I want to set again this field as auto_increment primary key without losing my data. How I can do this?
I tryed this:

```
ALTER TABLE name_table ADD COLUMN name_column serial primary key;
```

But with this I am losing my data and creating a new column, that I don't want

Comment: have you tried this? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/how-to-promote-an-existing-index-to-primary-key-in-postgresql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490014/adding-serial-to-existing-column-in-postgres and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593946/postgresql-reconfigure-existing-table-changing-primary-key-to-type-serial

Comment: I tryed this solution @a_horse_with_no_name, but not result

Comment: "*but no result*" is not a valid Postgres error message (you should add the **exact** commands you have tried - because I'm 100% that those questions _will_ solve your problem)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT some_name primary key (name_column);
```

Comment: yes Vivek, you are right, this is not working in Postgress because of the MODIFY

Comment: How about adding new constraint?

Answer (score 0):

For my suggestion,

1. backup your database first in sql or csv or xml or excel something 
   restore-able.
2. Then alter your table structure, column data type, from UI or command
3. Then if data recorded on your table are lost or gone, ***restore your
   backup data only, (not the structure of table)***

After that you have changed column data type and also get your required data. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I was trying several ways and I found this one and maybe also somebody later can use:

Create a sequenz: Sequenz is the way that Postgresql implement to generate auto_increment fields. Ones we have a auto_increment is also a primary key. Should not be like this, is not a rule, but in most of the cases a auto_increment field is a primary key.
To create a sequenz is like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE exemplo_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1 --the increment upgrate will be made 1 + 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 
    START 1 --the start counting is in 1
    CACHE 1;
```

After this is only to give this sequenz to the affected field using NEXTVAL, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL("exemplo_id_seq"::regclass);
```

Is working good without losing the data from old errors

Comment: This is exactly the solution from the questions I linked to (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9490014/330315) where you claimed that it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name you are right! the problem was that I just read the first answer in the post, and the second answer was a little down is exactly my solution. But thx anyway. The first answer look a little to complicated for me :)