# "null value in column ... violates not-null constraint" with INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: the first table, `customer_campaign_import`, has 7 columns. The second table, `customer_campaign`, has more columns than the first table with `id(uuid type)` as the primary key. Since `id` is the type `not-null constant` , when I execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO customer_campaign (store_name, store_address, store_city, store_province,     
 store_postal_code, lat, long)
SELECT * FROM customer_campaign_import;
```

It returns an error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

How do I generate a unique `id` for each row of the first table when inserting the first table into the second table?

Comment: Set your id to auto-increment with serial. For more read [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490014/adding-serial-to-existing-column-in-postgres

Answer (score 1):

ALTER the type of `id` to `serial` solved the problem.

Comment: You'd usually also have to set the initial value of the sequence.