# Postgresql 9.4, Make existing primary key as SERIAL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using postgresql 9.4. I want to change existing primary key with serial. My query is not working. Anybody know how to do this?

```
Alter table 'table_name' alter column id BIGSERIAL;
```

There should be a single query to modify a particular column. I didn't see that

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTik2hgCmweE39jemA6p4xPUjh8Gv_QsWdT7uL5UV@mail.gmail.com

Comment: ... + don't forget to specify `OWNED BY` clause for `CREATE SEQUENCE`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding 'serial' to existing column in Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490014/adding-serial-to-existing-column-in-postgres)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq
   OWNED BY table_name.id;

ALTER TABLE table_name
   ALTER id
      SET DEFAULT nextval('table_name_id_seq'::regclass);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what is regclass stands for. Will it be same while executing this query or it is the data base name ?

Comment: It is an [object identifier type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html). Essentially, it is a short way to convert an object name to an object identifier (`oid`).