# Postgresql add primary key as serial using contraint

Tags: postgresql, constraints, primary-key

I have a table which has an Id column as int but not mentioned as a primary key. Now I want to add primary key constraint as serial. I've seen this question [Postgresql 9.4, Make existing primary key as SERIAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847396/postgresql-9-4-make-existing-primary-key-as-serial) however this is using `alter table` statement while my intention is doing that with constraint. Is there any way to do that like below?

`constraint "PK_tablename" serial primary key ("Id")`

Comment: Note that serial is discouraged when using a current Postgres version in favor of `identity` columns.

Comment: Oh, thanks for warning. What's the best approach to create auto incremented PKs?

Comment: Has your table already have a PK?

Comment: No, there is a column named Id but not PK yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the constraint and the `identity` property in a single statement:

```
alter table the_table
    add constraint pk_the_table primary key (id),
    alter id add generated always as identity;
```

As you most probably have already data in your table, you need to adjust the sequence used by the identity clause:

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('the_table', 'id'), max(id))
from the_table;
```