# Update primary key while inserting list into table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that should contain a unique list of values ('activityid') from the other tables in the database. I can generate the list of unique values, but when I try to add it to the table (which is empty to start with), PostgreSQL returns the error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

This is my SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_activityid(activityid1)
SELECT distinct activityid from
(select activityid from d115ablackboxes
union select activityid from d115afilecabinets
union select activityid from d115arolledmaps
union select activityid from rockboxes1040)
as activityid
```

How can I have SQL add a value to the column 'id' at the same time as the INSERT command? Or, is there another workaround?

Answer (score 1):

If you define the 'id' as serial then it should automatically be assigned an incremented value.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/datatype.html
See bigserial or serial

Comment: I had tried changing the column type to serial, but since that's not apparently a true type it returned an error. After your suggestion, I tried Googling again and saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9490532/5900093), and an adaptation of that allowed my original command to work. Good to know.