# postgresql serial pk reverts to integer after restore

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, restore, autonumber

I built a db with serial type for the pks, I migrated to another server and the pk columns are now integer and as a result I cannot add new data due to the not null restriction of a pk. Is there any Alter command which can fix this?

Comment: If you "migrate" via pg_dump+pg_restore, you won't get this "problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SERIAL is not a data type in postgresql just a convenience word when creating tables that makes the column an integer type and adds auto-incrementing. All you have to do is add back auto-incrementing (a sequence) to the column and make sure its next value is greater than anything in the table.

[This question covers adding serial to an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490014/adding-serial-to-existing-column-in-postgres)

[This answer explains how to reset the counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5342503/4046595)

Comment: My choosen solution:  
SELECT MAX(ticket_id) + 1 FROM tickets_ticket;  
CREATE SEQUENCE tickets_ticket_a_seq START WITH 25;  
ALTER TABLE tickets_ticket ALTER COLUMN ticket_id SET DEFAULT nextval('tickets_ticket_a_seq');