# PostgreSQL - create an auto-increment column for non-primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, parse-platform, parse-server, postgresql-9.5

I am with PostgreSQL 9.5 X64 integrated with the open-source Parse Server. My table has the following structure.

```
objectId (text with fixed 10 characters),
item_id (integer),
item_name (text with various length)
```

The `objectId` is the primary key due to use of Parse Server. It is automatically generated by Parse Server. The `item_id` is not a primary key. I would like to have `item_id` automatically increment by 1 when a new record is created. How can this be achieved in Create Table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try making the `item_id` column `SERIAL`.  I don't know whether or not it's possible to alter the current `item_id` column to make it serial, so we might have to drop that column and then add it back, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP COLUMN item_id;
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN item_id SERIAL;
```

If there is data in the `item_id` column already, it may not make sense from a serial point of view, so hopefully there is no harm in deleting it.

Comment: Serial is just a shorthand when creating the table, afterwards you’d create a sequence and edit the default value to `nextval(‘sequencename’)` to achieve the same.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen If you're commenting with regards to how to handle the existing data fine, but in [modern versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944499/how-to-add-an-auto-incrementing-primary-key-to-an-existing-table-in-postgresql) of Postgres, the one-liner I gave should suffice for adding a serial column.

Comment: Yes, it was for your before-edit comment, and works if the data needs to be kept. Otherwise your suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Add a default value with a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mytable_item_id_seq OWNED BY mytable. item_id;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER item_id SET DEFAULT nextval('mytable_item_id_seq');
```

To make that work, you have to exclude the `item_id` column from all `INSERT` statrments, because the default value is only used if no value is specified for the column.

Comment: Thanks, this would've taken me ages to figure out. I inserted through dbeaver and ID was generated, through hibernate I received NOT NULL CONSTRAINT VIOLATION